# How to program in OpenGL 3.0? (no higher)

Tags: opengl

I want to learn OpenGL 3.0. I have made a small program in OpenGL 1.1 (lwjgl), however answers on StackOverflow reccomend learning modern OpenGL, with stuff like Vertex Buffer Objects, vertex and frangment shaders.

I have started using the [ogldev tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/). However, my graphics card, an Intel HD graphics card, only supports up to OpenGL 3.0 (with Mesa 10.1 on Linux), <strike>and when I compile the second tutorial's code I can see a dot, but when I compile the third tutorial's code I can't see a triangle (despite the only difference being the number of vertices);</strike>

How do I know what functions are not present in OpenGL 3.0, but are in other versions of OpenGL 3.x, and what should I replace them with?

Comment: What language are you using (you mentioned lwjgl initially)? Most of the Java language bindings are actually split up into namespaces, such that you have to do something to the effect: `import ...opengl.GL30` in order to have access to functions introduced in OpenGL 3.0. Used properly, this keeps the set of available functions ***"pure"***, you won't be able to call functions that are from GL 3.1+ if you don't import them. A good IDE may even see your exact set of imports and only list the functions from your versions in auto-complete lists, etc.

Comment: I am  using C with GLEW. I retried it anytime I use glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, int, int) I get the same dot at the center no matter what I pass as the vertex data.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know if a functionality is available in a given OpenGL version is by looking at the documentation. The [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page) is a good start.

Dealing with this is rather clumsy in OpenGL, since it relies heavily on extensions and hardware specific stuff that you have to test for availability at runtime before using. There are many good libraries to help you with that, such as [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and [Regal](https://github.com/p3/regal).

Comment: I am already using GLEW, and all the functions I'm using seem to be using exist in 3.0